# Some fields are not sorting properly in view

Tags: sorting, drupal-7, formatting, directory, view

I'm trying to create a directory list in view. But some of the fields are not properly sorting.

See the below image for my view configuration.
[image]

And the output of the view.
[image]

Please anyone help me to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you likely have a space (i.e. " ") at the beginning of your titles, or some other character that isn't displaying.